# What does Google Pub/Sub's topic/send_request_latencies metric measure

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I cannot find documentation besides the very basic https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#pubsub/topic/send_request_latencies on what the metric measures.

I assume that despite its name it is *not* the latency perceived by the publisher app as that would have to be measured at/by the publisher app itself. Additionally the metric is per topic, while I would expect the publish operation as executed on the publisher app to not be subject to differing latency depending on target topic.

Could you offer any insight?

Answer (score 1):

The `topic/send_request_latencies` metric measures the time spent processing a publish request in the service itself for a given topic. To get a full picture of latency, you would have to record some custom metrics to track from the time the client calls publish to the time it receives a response.